# Hold reference to downloaded DynamoDB data

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a class holding a DynamoDB model (I cut the # of variables for brevity, but they're all Optional Strings:

```
import AWSCore
import AWSDynamoDB

@objcMembers class Article: AWSDynamoDBObjectModel, AWSDynamoDBModeling {

  var _articleSource: String?

  class func dynamoDBTableName() -> String {
    return "article"
  }

  class func hashKeyAttribute() -> String {
    return "_articleId"
  }

  class func rangeKeyAttribute() -> String {
    return "_articleUrl"
  }

  override class func jsonKeyPathsByPropertyKey() -> [AnyHashable: Any] {
    return [
      "_articleSource" : "articles.articleSource",          
    ]
  }
}
```

In my View Controller, I'm downloading data from the table and storing each article in an array like this:

```
let dynamoDbObjectMapper = AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper.default()
var allArticles = [AnyObject]()

func getArticles(completed: @escaping DownloadComplete) {
  let scanExpression = AWSDynamoDBScanExpression()
  scanExpression.limit = 50
  self.dynamoDbObjectMapper.scan(Article.self, expression: scanExpression).continueWith(block: { (task:AWSTask<AWSDynamoDBPaginatedOutput>!) -> Any? in
  if let error = task.error as NSError? {
    print("The request failed. Error: \(error)")
  } else if let paginatedOutput = task.result {
    for article in paginatedOutput.items as! [Article] {
      self.allArticles.append(article)
    }
  }
  return(self.allArticles)
  })
  completed()
}
```

When I try to work with the data that should be stored in `allArticles` the array is empty. However, the array holds articles when I break execution in the download block where articles are being appended. How can I hold reference to the downloaded data? My use of a completion block was my attempt.

Edit: `allArticles` is of type `[AnyObject]` because I'm attempting to store objects from 3 different classes total in the same array to make it easier to work with in a TableView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The array wasn't empty after all, I just didn't realize this was all async (duh...)

I just needed:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.tableView.reloadData()
  }
```

in place of `completed()` in the `getArticles()` func